# Reading and Editing XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file which contains employee details. How can i edit the existing employee names in that MXL file using C# .NET.

Here is the xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Employees>
    <Employee id="1">
        <Name>Employee 1</Name>
        <Designation>SE </Designation>
        <Qualification>MCA </Qualification>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id="2">
        <Name>Employee 2</Name>
        <Designation>SE </Designation>
        <Qualification>MCA </Qualification>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id="3">
        <Name>Employee 3</Name>
        <Designation>SE </Designation>
        <Qualification>MCA </Qualification>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

How can i edit the employee names. I am new to xml. For example using Console Application

Comment: You forget `c#-2.0` tag.

Comment: @SonerGönül   i guess in c#2.0 we can't able to use XDocument, System.Xml.Linq. That's what i haven't mention 2.0.

Comment: You can create model and load xml file using it. Then you can select concrete object and manipulate as you want.

Comment: @user3121733, this is fairly trivial. I think you should first go trough a couple of tutorials and afterwards try again or come back with some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple do that using Linq to Xml.

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
...
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"Your xml file path goes here"); // or XDocument.Parse("Your xml string goes here");
xDoc.Root.Elements("Employee").First(xe => xe.Attribute("id").Value == "1").Element("Name").Value = "your value";
```

Here is a good reference for head start: [Programming Guide (LINQ to XML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387087.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can use XML Serialization, in my opinion this is the most comfortable way
of working with c# and xml,

some examples are here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.110).aspx